# Проблема с выгрузкой результата запроса к БД в CSV (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, csv

Проблема следующая. Запускаю скрипт

```
select
WI.StartDate AS 'Дата начала',
WI.EndDate AS 'Дата завершения', 
PTCA.CommentCS AS 'Комментарий КС',
PTCA.CommentSBtoCS AS 'Комментарий СБ',
PTCA.CommentOAtoCS AS 'Комментарий ОА для КС',
PTCA.CommentOAtoSB AS 'Комментарий ОА для СБ',
PTCA.CommentFromDeal AS 'Комментарий к сделке'
from P_TypeCreditAnket PTCA (nolock)
left JOIN WorkflowInstance WI ON PTCA.WorkflowInstance=WI.Id
where
WI.StartDate >= '2018-06-01'
AND WI.IsEmulation=0
Order by 1
```

Далее получаю результат выполнения скрипта и нажимаю правой клавишей Save Results AS. Либо выделяю и Копировать с заголовками и вставляю в Excel. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И получаю вот такую чехарду. Если копировать по столбцам тоже какая-то чехарда с данными получается. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Результат выполнения где, в какой утилите/приложении?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov SMSS